# HTTP 501 for java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, http, exception, rest

I have a generic REST service layer written to Java modules which can be plugged in. If any of the desired operation is not supported by a Module (GET/POST/PUT/DELETE of a Resource), the module throws java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException or an equivalent Exception Type that I have.

So, can I return a HTTP 501 Error Code to the client in this case?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this case you should use `405` *Method Not Allowed* (all quotes [from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)):

> A request was made of a resource using a request method not supported
>   by that resource; for example, using GET on a form which requires data
>   to be presented via POST, or using PUT on a read-only resource.

`501` is reasonable:

> The server either **does not recognise the request method**, or it lacks the ability to fulfill the request.

but I would keep it for operations that you plan to implement in the near future.

Comment: Thanks Tomas. Just to clarify, if a client is trying to create a resource /rest/module_name/Person and create() is not supported by the module identified by "module_name", it is treated as a client request problem and thrown a 405 rather than a server side problem by returning 501? The reason I ask is that, 4XX are client related error codes whilst 5XX are server related.

Comment: @BlueDiamond: well, is it you (API provider) doing something wrong (5xx) or the client is using the API incorrectly (4xx)?